# Python Function that counts number of alphabetic characters, keeps track of how many times “e” Appears, utilizes .isalpha

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have to write a function that receives a string as input. 
My function should count the number of alphabetic characters (a through z, or A through Z) in the text and also keep track of how many times the letter 'e' (upper or lowercase) appears.

My function should return an analysis of the text, something like this:

> The text contains 240 alphabetic characters, of which 105 (43.75%) are ‘e’.

And I will need to make use of the `str.isalpha` function, which should be used like this:

```
"a".isalpha() # => evaluates to True
"3".isalpha() # => evaluates to False
"&".isalpha() # => False
" ".isalpha() # => False

mystr = "Q"
mystr.isalpha() # => True
```

I am struggling with the .isalpha function which I am assuming we are trying to use to distinguish the alphabetical characters from the special characters ie: `",?!/"`...etc. I am just not entirely sure how to use it. I have looked on Stackoverflow and tried to use it the way I saw some people use it. This is my code so far:

```
def analyze_text(text):
    "".join(i for i in text if i.isalpha())
    char = text.count('') - 1
    char_e = text.count('e') + text.count('E')
    char_ediv = str(char/char_e * 100.0)

    result = print("The text contains", char, "alphabetic characters, of which", char_e,"("+ char_ediv  + "%" + ")" " are 'e'.")
    return result
```

My string should pass the following tests:

```
from test import testEqual

text1 = "Eeeee"
answer1 = "The text contains 5 alphabetic characters, of which 5 (100.0%) are 'e'."
testEqual(analyze_text(text1), answer1)

text2 = "Blueberries are tasteee!"
answer2 = "The text contains 21 alphabetic characters, of which 7 (33.3333333333%) are 'e'."
testEqual(analyze_text(text2), answer2)

text3 = "Wright's book, Gadsby, contains a total of 0 of that most common symbol ;)"
answer3 = "The text contains 55 alphabetic characters, of which 0 (0.0%) are 'e'."
testEqual(analyze_text(text3), answer3)
```

So far I have it passing the first test and then I get an error:

```
Error
UnboundLocalError: **local variable 'result' referenced before assignment on line 10**
Description
undefined
To Fix
undefined
```

Comment: The exception you describe doesn't make any sense with the code you've shown. Can you give us the full traceback (with proper formatting)? There are a number of issues with your code (such as doing the division backwards, and trying to save the return value of `print`), but those would cause other problems than what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

The `print()` function writes, i.e., "prints", a string in the console, which is different from a `return` from the function. You need to return the string you are printing.

```
result = "The text contains" + char + "alphabetic characters, of which" + char_e + "(" + char_ediv + "%" + ")" " are 'e'."
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Another error happens in the third test case because you have no "e" and therefore you divide by zero.

The fix would be to use a `if char_e`:

```
def analyze_text(text):
    text = "".join(i for i in text if i.isalpha())
    char = text.count('') - 1
    char_e = text.count('e') + text.count('E')
    if char_e:
        char_ediv = str(char/char_e * 100.0)
    else:
        char_ediv = str(0.0)
```

However some remarks:

- You had `"".join(i for i in text if i.isalpha())` without assigning it a variable. I fixed this above.
- You can use `text.lower().count('e')` instead of counting `e` and `E`.
- You don't need to count `''`, you can simply use `len()` to count all remaining characters.
- `print` returns `None` so you always return `None`.

Whenever you use string addition several times, you could replace it with a format:

```
"The text contains", char, "alphabetic characters, of which", char_e,"("+ char_ediv  + "%" + ")" " are 'e'."
```

better would be:

```
result = ("The text contains {} alphabetic characters, of which {} ({} %) are 'e'."
          "".format(char, char_e, char_ediv))
```

The updated function looks like this:

```
def analyze_text(text):
    text = "".join([i for i in text if i.isalpha()])
    char = len(text)
    char_e = text.lower().count('e')
    if char_e:
        char_ediv = str(char/char_e * 100.0)
    else:
        char_ediv = str(0.0)

    result = ("The text contains {} alphabetic characters, of which {} ({} %) are 'e'."
              "".format(char, char_e, char_ediv))
    return result
```